# Getting attachment image from forward email

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have this issue where i cant download the attachment images in a forward message.
Content id for this images are like: cid:companylogo.jpg@1231.1231.

What my application does is read emails, donwload images upload them to picture library in sharepoint and then change the src value of this images from the original html for the new urls which are the ones of the sharepoint picture library.

I got this working pefectly, but yesterday we were trying with forward messages, and the application couldn't handle this type of attachments.
For starters when opening outlook the email appears as it has no attachments, we did some research that it does not has attachments but makes reference to the original email which was then forward.

I have no clue on how to get this image from the forward image.

If anyone has any ideas or resources there are much welcome.

Sorry for bad english not my native language

Comment: i just discovered that is not a problem if its a forward email. This happens when someone does a copy paste of an email and sends it. I have no idea how to manage this type of images as they are not detected as attachments